# Java Interface Reflection Alternatives

Tags: java, generics, reflection, interface

I am developing an application that makes use of the Java Interface as *more* than a Java interface, i.e., During runtime, the user should be able to list the available methods within the interface class, which may be anything:

```
private Class<? extends BaseInterface> interfaceClass.
```

At runtime, I would like to enum the available methods, and then based on what the user chooses, invoke some method.

My question is:  Does the Java "Interface" architecture provide any method for me to peek and invoke methods without using the Reflection API?

I wish there were something like this (Maybe there is):

```
private Interface<? extends BaseInterface> interfaceAPI;

public void someMethod(){
 interfaceAPI.listMethods();
 interfaceAPI.getAnnotations();
}
```

Maybe there is some way to use Type Generics to accomplish what I want?

Thanks,

Phaedrus

Comment: There are other ways, but they are far worse IMHO.  You haven't said why you don't want to use reflection. Perhaps your concerns can be addressed.

Comment: you can generate code on the fly (and load it via some custom classloader)... but that's what reflection actually does.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is exactly what Reflection was built for.

Answer (score 1):

> My question is: Does the Java "Interface" architecture provide any method for me to peek and invoke methods without using the Reflection API?

a) No, reflection is the only way to do that

b) don't do that at all. If you want a dynamic language, use Groovy. It's syntax is (can be) almost identical to java, but it has most of this functionality built in already. (Many other languages will also work, but Groovy is closest to Java when comparing the syntax)

Comment: what's wrong w/ javascript? it's even available in java itself?

Comment: @bestsss nothing is wrong with JS, it's a great language, and I never said otherwise. But when you make a recommendation you have to start somewhere

Comment: I never implied you said anything about Javascript, just wondering how it's not the 1st choice.

Answer (score 1):

Reflection is the only way to list methods of an arbitrary object. Well, parsing the bytecode also works, but it's tedious.

Comment: That's a false statement. You can pretty much generate the code on the fly, Proxy and Reflection does that behind the scenes. It's possible to do it by hand just as fine.

Comment: @bestsss When you are given an `Object` instance, how do you list its methods "by hand" ?

Comment: @Bozho, you get its class (Object.getClass()) find the class resource `(ClassLoader.getResource(className.replace('.','\')+".class")`, load the resource, parse the Constant pool and it's done... Well, there are libraries to do so (bcel for instance), but that's the process.

Comment: ...actually both bcel and asm are part of Sun's JDK (not truly officially, though; but even Sun uses 'em), so no extra libraries are necessary either

Comment: Well, yeah, you can parse the bytecode. But the getResource(..) class may not work - a class doesn't necessarily need a `.class` file.

Comment: @Paŭlo Ebermann, that's hardly any reflection (Class is in `java.lang`)since naturally you can't do anything w/ the class itself. Historically Object had getClass() all the time but Reflection (`java.lang.reflect`) was introduced in java1.1 (and was quite slow but looked so damn glamorous)

Comment: @Bozho, yes, the class bytes may not available unless you install the loading classloader. VM, of course, supports listing itself, my actual point was mostly invoking the methods, not retrieving the meta information. (but yeah, you've edited and now the discussing looks a bit pointless)

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at [Apache Commons BeanUtils](http://commons.apache.org/beanutils/). It's an excellent library for programmatically discovering an object's methods and properties *easily* (i.e. without writing low-level reflection code). I've used it on several projects. It also provides an easier API for accessing those object members once they're discovered. [PropertyUtils](http://commons.apache.org/beanutils/api/org/apache/commons/beanutils/PropertyUtils.html) and [MethodUtils](http://commons.apache.org/beanutils/api/org/apache/commons/beanutils/MethodUtils.html) are good places to start.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately it looks like reflection is the only way to go. Unfortunate because reflection is not only slower but programming and maintaining is a hassle. So I suggest you use apache bean util library. (specifically [methodutils](http://commons.apache.org/beanutils/commons-beanutils-1.6.1/docs/api/org/apache/commons/beanutils/MethodUtils.html).)

Answer (score 0):

Although there's no way around reflection here, it can be made relatively painless if you use annotations to mark your callable methods. An example of this approach at work is the [javax.jws](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/javax/jws/package-summary.html) annotation set for webservices. The ideas used there can be really useful, you can define a display name for each of your methods/parameters for example.

Answer (score 0):

Reflection with Annotations is working Nicely

```
for (Method m : interfaceClass.getMethods()) {
         if (m.isAnnotationPresent(UIf.class)) {
            UIf x = m.getAnnotation(UIf.class);
            addDefinedCommand( new CommandDef(
                    interfaceClass, 
                    u, 
                    x.name().isEmpty() ? m.getName() : x.name(), 
                    x.description()) 
            );
         }
 }
```